# Problems with Gnuplot Gif

Tags: animation, gnuplot, gif

I am trying to make a gif of the solution of a partial differential equation. In some related posts I have found that I should split my data as follows:

```
-1.000000 0.000000
-0.600000 0.000000
-0.200000 0.654508
0.200000 0.654508
0.600000 0.000000
1.000000 0.000000
1.400000 0.000000
1.800000 0.000000
2.200000 0.000000
2.600000 0.000000
3.000000 0.000000


-1.000000 0.000000
-0.600000 0.000000
-0.200000 0.163627
0.200000 0.654508
0.600000 0.490881
1.000000 0.000000
1.400000 0.000000
1.800000 0.000000
2.200000 0.000000
2.600000 0.000000
3.000000 0.000000

...
```

and then I have read that something like that should work:

```
set terminal gif animate delay 100
set output 'name.gif'
stats 'data.dat' nooutput
do for [i=1:int(STATS_blocks)]{plot 'data.dat' every i using 1:2 with lines notitle}
```

but I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB1HU.gif). Whereas if I plot every data chunk alone it is completely different. What is wrong with my Gnuplot code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `index i` rather than `every i`